# How To Display SSRS Report In Angular 5 Application

Tags: angular, reporting-services

I am Trying to display the SSRS Reports using Angular 5,i have looked in to Angular 2 ngx-ssrs-reportviewer the below github repo is this enough, when i you the repo this has Zero Fork. am worried with work for me.

can any one suggest better solution

https://github.com/tycomo/ngx-ssrs-reportviewer

Answer (score 1):

we can't able to show SSRS report in angular. But you can convert and render your SSRS report as PDF using webapi and show it in your angular app using Iframe, popwindow and ng2-pdf-viewer.